# Show image in ejs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, image, ejs

I am using node with express. 
The project consists of an index page and a dashboard. Different routes and views are loaded into the dashboard. I want to integrate a loading gif until the data arrives. Everything is working. But I don't know how I can load the gif source in the ejs-view.

Here is the code snippet from coverage.ejs:

```
<div id="loading">
<img id="loading-image" src="../public/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading.." />
</div>
```

In the javascript console when I run the project there is this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/public/images/ajax-loader.gif 404 (Not Found)
```

I am using a jQuery script to update the page frequently. 
How can I insert the gif so that the page knows the source, where it comes from?

Comment: What does your `express.static()` look like?

Comment: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The src direction was wrong. It needs to be:

```
<div id="loading">
<img id="loading-image" src="./images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading.." />
</div>
```